# evince won't show PDF's not named like *.pdf

Tags: pdf, symbolic-link, ubuntu-14.04, latex, evince

I can view a PDF file `foo.pdf` with evince.

But when I rename it to `foo`, evince instead complains,
`Unable to open document "foo".  Error opening file: Permission denied [Close]`.  (Of course the perms haven't changed.)

If I try to view `foo` by making a symlink `bar.pdf` pointing at `foo`, evince similarly won't view `bar.pdf`.

On the other hand, evince *will* show a symlink to `foo.pdf`, no matter what the symlink is named.  So does evince care about the filename extension, or not?  This is perverse.

**How can I view a PDF file that's not named *.pdf?**
(arXiv's LaTeX file processing step has a "view" button that downloads a PDF named `view`.  I'd rather not rename that file every single time.  As stated above, `ln -s view view.pdf` doesn't fix things.  Maybe there's some other workaround like a background script that watches when `view`'s timestamp changes, and then literally copies it to `view.pdf`.)

Comment: `evince` doesn't care, at least version `3.20.1` that I have. Your error: `Error opening file: Permission denied [Close]` indicates that there is a problem with permissions, not with an extension. Most probably there is no read permission.

Comment: Permissions are fine; the error message is wrong.  
I have evince version 3.10.3, current for Ubuntu 14.  Should I resort to adding a PPA to get a bleeding-edge evince?

Comment: I'm not sure, I still think that permissions are incorrect. Post output of `ls -l view` and `file view`.

Comment: Hmm, ok. What do other say pdf viewers say, for example `zathura` or `okular`?

Comment: Thanks! Both zathura 0.2.6 and okular 0.19.3 show `view` correctly.  This may turn out to be the best workaround.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk evince v3.28.4 still has this bug three years later.  I'd accept your comment as an answer.